# Prove that exists a linear transformation base on kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that exists a linear transformation $T: (Z_5)^4 \to (Z_5)^4$ such that:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im}T &= \operatorname{Sp}\{(1,1,-1,1),(0,3,-2,2)\},\\ \operatorname{Ker}T &= \operatorname{Sp}\{(1,1,-1,1),(3,0,4,4),(3,3,2,-2)\}
\end{align}

Any direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please add to your post some more information. What have you tried?

Comment: The question is what can i try, i dont know how to approach this.

Comment: are you familiar with "Linear extension theorem"?

Comment: I get that $dim KerT = 3, dim ImT = 2$ which contradicts $5 = dim KerT + dim ImT = dim (Z_5)^4 = 4$ cuz $dim KerT = 3$ everytime i try to check it...

Comment: And yes, i am familiar with the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such transformation because of dimensionality problems, as you pointed out yourself. Here is what you would do if there did exist a linear transformation, maybe you have copied the vectors wrong?

Extract a basis from the image and kernel.

When done, write the kernel as the span of two linearly independent vectors, and find 2 vectors which are linearly independent of those. Since elements in the kernel are mapped to 0, define $T$ on the spanning vectors in the kernel to be $0$, and define $T$ on the two other vectors to be the spanning vectors of the image.

You now have a function defined on a basis of $(Z_5)^4$, which you can linearly extend to the whole space. Per linearity of this map, it has the right kernel and image.